# In TCL what is the best way to add 2 very long string formatted hex numbers?

Tags: tcl

I need to add 2 very long string formatted hex numbers using TCL. If the strings were short, I could use something like this:

```
set a "BEEF"
set b "F00D"

format "%X" [expr 0x$a+0x$b]
```

But my hex strings are very long and the output of the last line above will result in "integer value too large to represent". I am thinking of writing my own proc to either add the digits one by one (while keeping track of the carry) or break the string in smaller chunks then sum and merge together. Are there any better solutions out there? Like maybe a built-in TCL command that can help?

EDIT: I need to use TCL 8.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I wrote up this answer before the Tcl 8.4 requirement was known. This solution works with Tcl 8.5 and later versions. I'm leaving it here since it may still be useful to someone else.)

Try using

```
proc add {a b} {
    expr {[tcl::mathfunc::entier 0x$a] + [tcl::mathfunc::entier 0x$b]}
}
```

The function `entier` returns an unlimited integer value. I tried it with

```
add beefbeefbeefbeefbeefbeefbeefbeefbeefbeef f00df00df00df00df00df00df00df00df00df00d
# => 2460523363851273071965346074055892853050711060220
```

which may be good enough. I have no idea if the answer is correct, nor can I figure out why the function is called "entier", which is usually an alternative name for the `floor` function.

Note also that the `format` command won't be able to convert numbers of this size to hexadecimal notation.

(After swooning over my own cleverness I realized that this will work too, unlimited integers apparently being the default nowadays: (note still Tcl 8.6))

```
proc add {a b} {
    expr [list 0x$a + 0x$b]
}
```

Documentation: [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm), [mathfunc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the TCL application I'm using (which is embedded in another application) is 8.4 :(. And I believe the "entier" function was added in a later version.

Comment: @Arash: yes, it's an 8.5 addition. AFAICT there is no "forwards compatibility" replacement code for it either.

Comment: I guess it's called 'entier' since it's the translation for 'entire' in french which thus means that it doesn't truncate the values and keep the precision.

Comment: The word"entier" is actually French for "integer".  Algol used it for the name of its integer truncation function.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `::math::bignum` package from tcllib.

```
package require math::bignum

set a [::math::bignum::fromstr $yourlargestring1 16]
set b [::math::bignum::fromstr $yourlargestring2 16]
set c [::math::bignum::add $a $b]
set result [::math::bignum::tostr $c 16]
```

Docs: http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/tcllib/math/bignum.html#1

Comment: +1 but it would be tidier to `namespace import ::math::bignum::*`